# ThreadLocal same instance returned for different threads

Tags: java, runnable, thread-local

Below is my code.
As per my understanding different object for different threads are returned by ThreadLocal.

However as per the output same object of simpleDateFormat is returned for all 100 thread, which is evident from the output.

Output shows the different hashcode for different thread, however same hashcode for formatter object

What is the reason of this behavior?

**Code :-**

```
    public class PasswordUtils {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        PasswordUtils passwordUtils = new PasswordUtils();
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i++) {
            Runnable r = () -> passwordUtils.print();
            new Thread(r).start();
        }    
        
        
    }

    private void print() {
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = Container.formatter.get();
        
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().hashCode() + ".." + simpleDateFormat.hashCode());
        
        //System.out.println(simpleDateFormat.format(new Date()));
    }
    
}


class Container{
    
    
    public static ThreadLocal<SimpleDateFormat> formatter = new ThreadLocal<SimpleDateFormat> () {

        @Override
        protected SimpleDateFormat initialValue() {
            return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        }

        @Override
        public SimpleDateFormat get() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return super.get();
        }
        
        
        
    };
    
}
```

**Partial Output -**

```
1987792509..-159776256
1454218797..-159776256
1538961195..-159776256
543422400..-159776256
1174433642..-159776256
1478339661..-159776256
1225887310..-159776256
877863801..-159776256
1780641507..-159776256
1149839869..-159776256
285105474..-159776256
1805341503..-159776256
1046456602..-159776256
1587844268..-159776256
184214807..-159776256
1413925925..-159776256
1524435618..-159776256
1148128963..-159776256
1745632619..-159776256
1111741636..-159776256
799003225..-159776256
1913056178..-159776256
468763350..-159776256
1774308692..-159776256
1156098485..-159776256
1801860764..-159776256
1027791388..-159776256
580473608..-159776256
521077568..-159776256
205112696..-159776256
543478023..-159776256
233725246..-159776256
1389707361..-159776256
2098719925..-159776256
1934917117..-159776256
1379545873..-159776256
316905017..-159776256
1015697085..-159776256
680699774..-159776256
1375267811..-159776256
1347156237..-159776256
1509621224..-159776256
1083785111..-159776256
1478175754..-159776256
856529417..-159776256
1193485652..-159776256
682509788..-159776256
902590073..-159776256
43405057..-159776256
688069042..-159776256
790596691..-159776256
868880743..-159776256
796762285..-159776256
714689675..-159776256
1748149209..-159776256
45304792..-159776256
662040031..-159776256
711284131..-159776256
2115622748..-159776256
355026544..-159776256
2130317957..-159776256
1739356891..-159776256
788070019..-159776256
1821155423..-159776256
881224713..-159776256
1747515031..-159776256
833849678..-159776256
```

Comment: I see two problems here 1) You declared the variable static, so only one instance of SimpleDateFormat exists 2) As mentioned below the hashCode is dependent on the pattern, unless you change the pattern the hashCode won't change 3) I would say you have to get rid of static and then `(new Container()).formatter.get()` to create new instance everytime

Comment: You should not use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`, as they are obsolete. Use classes from the `java.time` package instead.

Comment: @Declare there is no problem with declaring SimpleDataFormat as static.

Comment: For precision: the `ThreadLocal` is declared static, which is not a problem. It would have been a problem to declare the `SimpleDateFormat` static, but the code doesn’t do that. Leaving aside that using `SimpleDateFormat` at all is a separate problem since it is a notorious troublemaker of a class. Use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and avoid the need for any formatter at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the implementation of hashCode in SimpleDateFormat:

```
public int hashCode()
{
    return pattern.hashCode();
    // just enough fields for a reasonable distribution
}
```

You are not seeing the same instance, but all your instances have the same hashCode.

You can use reference equality to determine whether two instances are the same:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class Example
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SimpleDateFormat f1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yy");
        SimpleDateFormat f2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yy");
        System.out.println("f.equals(f2): " + f1.equals(f2));
        System.out.println("f1 == f2 " + (f1 == f2));
        System.out.println("f1 == f1 " + (f1 == f1));
    }
}
```

Comment: Then how can one verify if we are getting different objects or the same in above code (please explain with code) ?